# Wordpress login page keeps refreshing on login -- setup on Webmin

Tags: php, wordpress, webmin

The Wordpress login page keeps refreshing on login.  No error notices.  It just clears the login form and reloads.  This is set up with the base Wordpress install...no plugins and using twentytwentytwo theme.

I am also getting a message "Installation failed: 0" when trying to add a plugin.  But I am able to install via WP-CLI.

More details:

- Database is connected and working fine (I can deactivate and activate plugins).  WP-CLI is working fine.
- I have tried deactivate .htaccess and restarting apache
- the site is setup through Webmin.  My hunch is there are some permission issues, but all of the files have the correct permissions and user/group assigned.  I have tried both root:root and apache:apache.  The OS is CentOS 8.
- I have also tried deactivating the firewall, and looked through the apache logs.
- the only issue I see in WP site health is this: The required module, gd, is not installed, or has been disabled.

Any help here would be much appreciated

- I have set files permissions...755 for directories and 644 for files.  As well as trying different user/groups - root:root and apache:apache.
- I have tried installing via SSH/wp-cli and through the standard wordpress package zip download.

Comment: Any related errors in the web server and / or PHP error log?

Comment: One possible thing, check your `wp-config.php` if there's a cookie domain **and** if it matches your domain. `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'yourdomain.com')
`. If the domain is different, then the cookie for your session is not set and you are redirected back to login. But I'm not aware this would cause your other described behaviour regarding plugins.

Comment: @CBroe there's nothing relevant in the server errors logs.

Comment: @AlexBerger I updated the wp-config with this line, but this doesn't seem to help.